# ConsumerRebalanceListener and/or ContainerProperties override per container

Tags: spring-kafka

Spring Kafka currently provides a way of defining a user *ConsumerRebalanceListener* through the ContainerProperties. As this ContainerProperties is linked to the container factory, it can be a bit tricky to define a different listener for each container. This would require a separate factory for each listener.

So, wouldn't it make sense to add a new property to the *KafkaListener* annotation such as

```
KafkaListener(... rebalanceListener="beanNameOfTheRebalanceListener"...)
```

An alternative would be to allow ContainerProperties overrides per container.

```
KafkaListener(... containerProperties="beanNameOfTheContainerProperties"...)
```

This second approach could be accompanied by a way of creating a ContainerProperties class from another (ContainerProperties.from()), to avoid having to link each property manually...

Any feedback or opinion on this? I may contribute on this request.

Answer (score 1):

To customize individual containers, add a `ContainerCustomizer` to the container factory:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#container-factory

```java
factory.setContainerCustomizer(container -> {
    container.getContainerProperties().set...
});
```

If you give each listener an `id`, you can use `container.getListenerId()` to determine which container is being customized (or use any other properties e.g. `groupId`).

Given that we already have this mechanism, I don't think we want to complicate things further by adding more properties to the annotation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very quick reply. I was not aware about that feature. Something great would be to add a new containerCustomizer property (bean name of that customizer) on the KafkaListener annotation. So that, we may avoid the filtering and have a clear link between the container and the customizer.

Comment: It would certainly be possible to do that - override the default factory customizer (if provided). Feel free to open a new feature issue on GitHub.

Comment: Github issue has been created https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2825 - I can drop a PR if it can help.